# Spark SQL - Joined Dataset appears to have been coalesced into fewer partitions

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am performing an inner join where the left and right Datasets have been repartitioned by the same column into 2001 partitions within the same job.

I am expecting the joined dataset to also have 2001 partitions yet it has 200 which is the default value for spark.sql.shuffle.partitions.

Could anyone advise under what circumstances spark may decide to reduce the number of partitions on a joined Dataset?

Regards

Terry.

Comment: Many answers already on this forum on this topic. RDD vs DF, DS though.

Answer (score 0):

OK - it appears under some circumstances the LHS Dataset may be much smaller or than the RHS dataset or indeed empty. If I explicitly broadcast the LHS Dataset then the joined Dataset has 2001 partitions as expected.